# How to create a JSONArray with GSON

Tags: android, json, gson, arrays

Hi in my project i need to create a JSONArray type with the GSON class

```
    {
  "message": [
    "msg 1",
    "msg 2",
    "msg 3"
  ],
  "asec": [
    "asec 1",
    "asec 2",
    "asec 3"
  ]
}
```

I know how to create JSONArray with key value in GSON for eg:

```
  [
  {
    "message1": "msg 1",
    "asc": "asc 1"
  },
  {
    "message1": "msg 2",
    "asc": "asc 2"
  },
  {
    "message1": "msg 3",
    "asc": "asc 3"
  }
]
```

But i dont know how to create JSONArray type can any one help me

Comment: A JSON Array is just a list of serialized objects. So if you simply: Gson().toJson(YOUR ARRAY OF OBJECTS) - You should end up with a nice JSONArray object.

Comment: @LokiSinclair can i have any sample for this plz

Comment: @Jagan Check my answer my below to create jsonObject you required using Google's Gson library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the class:

```
public class JsonStructure{
    public String[] message;
    public String[] asec;
}
```

using it:

```
JsonStructure json = new JsonStructure();
json.message = new String[]{"msg 1", "msg 2", "msg 3"};
json.asec = new String[]{"asec 1", "asec 2", "asec 3"};
Gson gson = new Gson();
String output = gson.toJson(json);
//convert from string
JsonStructure fromString = gson.fromJson(output, JsonStructure.class);
```

For more details on Google's gson please take a look at https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: Dude how can i get the same JSONArray value using GSON i know it's gson.fromJson() but i dont know how to get

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ArrayBean {
    ArrayList<String> message = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> asec = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

create bean class above arraybean,   then u can add the values on your main class and print the output.

```
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   ArrayBean arrayBean = new ArrayBean();

        arrayBean.message.add("msg 1");
        arrayBean.message.add("msg 2");
        arrayBean.message.add("msg 3");

        arrayBean.asec.add("asec 1");
        arrayBean.asec.add("asec 2");
        arrayBean.asec.add("asec 3");


        Log.d("rvg",""+gson.toJson(arrayBean));
```

Comment: Dude how can i get the same JSONArray value using GSON

Comment: i know it's gson.fromJson() but i dont know how to get

Comment: String response == //your http response;
  gson.fromJson(response, ArrayBean.class);

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to create JsonObject you desired.

```
String[] msgArray = new String[]{"msg 1", "msg 2", "msg 3"};
String[] asecArray = new String[]{"asec 1", "asec 2", "asec 3"};

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject(); //Json Object

obj.add("message", gson.toJsonTree(msgArray));
obj.add("asec", gson.toJsonTree(asecArray));

String jsonString = gson.toJson(obj);  //Json String
```

Refer [Gson documentation](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for more details